# Ссылка в мобильном приложении vue.js на сторонний сайт

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, cordova, href

Делаю приложение на vue.js монтирую его кордовой в apk \ ipa
как в приложении разместить кнопку с ссылкой на сторонний сайт, что бы при нажатии она открывалась в установленном браузере на телефоне, а не пыталось открыться в самом приложении!
делал так:

```
 <div class="menubut" onclick="location.href='https://google.com/'">Перейти на сайт</div>
```

так:

```
 <a href="https://goodle.com/"><div class="menubut">Перейти на сайт</div></a>
```

и вот так:

```
<a href="https://goodle.com/" target="_blank"><div class="menubut">Перейти на сайт</div></a>
```

но всё это не открывает сайт в браузере пользователя, как сделать что бы выскакивало что то вроде окошка "в какой прогрме хотите открыть ссылку" - как это обычно бывает в других приложениях?